# How do I properly pass an array in C#

Tags: c#

Heyy, so I'm having a little trouble with a program I'm working on for class. I'm thinking that the error I'm making is small, but I just can't seem to find it.
It seems as though my sInsults array is not getting saved properly, or that it is not being passed the strings correctly. Someone please point out my obvious mistake lol.
And don't judge on the hilarious insults, they are specified by my teacher xD

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Utilities;
using System.IO;

namespace ICA27
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string[] sNames = { "Al ", "John ", "JD ", "Bill ", "Ross " };
            string[] sVerbs = { "talks to ", "licks ", "runs ", "flushes ", "uses " };
            string[] sObjects = { "safeway carts.", "Microsoft.", "old mops.", "dead cows.", "Vista." };
        string[] sInsults = MakeInsults(sNames, sVerbs, sObjects);
        SaveInsults(sInsults);
    }
    static string[] MakeInsults(string[] sNames, string[] sVerbs, string[] sObjects)
    {
        string sString = "How many insults do you want to make? ";
        int iInput = 0;
        CUtilities.GetValue(out iInput, sString, 5, 100);
        string[] sInsults = new string[iInput];
        Random rNum = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i< iInput; i++)
        {
            sInsults[i] = sNames[rNum.Next(sNames.Length)] + sVerbs[rNum.Next(sVerbs.Length)] + sObjects[rNum.Next(sObjects.Length)];
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Array of insults have been created!");
        return sInsults;
    }
    static void SaveInsults(string[] sInsults)
    {
        Console.Write("What would you like the file to be named? ");
        string sName = Console.ReadLine();
        StreamWriter swName;
        Console.Write("Would you like to append the file? ");
        string sAnswer = Console.ReadLine();
        sAnswer = sAnswer.ToUpper();
        if ((sAnswer == "YES")||(sAnswer == "Y"))
        {
            swName = new StreamWriter(sName, true);
        }
        else
        {
            swName = new StreamWriter(sName);
        }
        for (int iI = 0; iI < sInsults.Length; iI++)
            swName.WriteLine(sInsults[iI]);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: This looks fine to me... please post the error you're getting.

Comment: "Bill uses Microsoft/Vista" seems like a pretty good insult to me.

Comment: I'm not getting an error, it just seems as though my insults aren't saving to a text document. The file is being made, but is empty. Am I maybe supposed to open it with something other than notepad?
I've tried doing a step-into, no results.

And yea, my teacher has a decent sense of humor ;)

Comment: I can almost run this, what is a CUtilities.GetValue?

Comment: @user3499181: you need to close your streamWriter object `swName` after writing the content using statement `swName.Close()` check my answer.

Comment: Forgot to close the file - very common mistake!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Solution 1 :** You need to close your `StreamWriter` instance variable `swName`.

Try This:

```
for (int iI = 0; iI < sInsults.Length; iI++)
            swName.WriteLine(sInsults[iI]);

swName.Close(); //add this statement
```

**Solution 2:**

I Would suggest you to enclose the `StreamWriter` Object declaration within `using{}` block to ensure that your objects gets disposed properly.

Try This:

```
using(StreamWriter swName = new StreamWriter(sName, true))
{
   for (int iI = 0; iI < sInsults.Length; iI++)
    swName.WriteLine(sInsults[iI]);
}
```

**Solution 3:** You can still use using block by just checking the if condition.

Try This:

```
   bool IsAppend = false;
   if ((sAnswer == "YES")||(sAnswer == "Y"))
    {
        IsAppend = true;
    }

    using(StreamWriter swName = new StreamWriter(sName, IsAppend))
    {
       for (int iI = 0; iI < sInsults.Length; iI++)
        swName.WriteLine(sInsults[iI]);
    }
```

Comment: I would also refactor the code to only create the StreamWriter in one place, and use a `using { }` block

Comment: Thank you man!!
This is my first time using StreamWriter, I didn't know you had to do that.
Greatly appreciated!

Comment: Wouldn't that always append the file then? I only have to if/else because my teacher specifically wants the option of appending. Otherwise, I totally agree. And I will definitely mark once it allows me to.

Comment: @user3499181: check my solution 3

Comment: Hmm, didn't even think about that :p. Well, thank you very much :) Also, thanks for ensuring I will continue to use this site. This was my first question, I'm very impressed with the speed of the answers, as well as the knowledge. As far as I'm concerned, a new take on a program is always great :)